# Sorting by number of string matches within Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model that has a tags field which is a comma-separated list of tags.  Given a list of tags strings, I've constructed a queryset that finds instances of my model that have at least one of the tags.  I have this working like so:

```
tag_list = ["tag1", "tag2"]

MyModel.objects.filter(
    reduce(
        lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(tags__icontains=tag) for tag in tag_list]))
```

But now I want to sort the queryset in decreasing order by the number matching tags each item has.  I've been trying to find the right way to annotate a field that would contain the match-count but haven't had much luck.  Any pointers?

Comment: I think it would be more _efficient_ to do the sorting in python rather than the database. Once you get a `list` of objects that have at least one tag, you can sort it using the `MyModel.tags.count()` attribute passed to the sorting comparison - it'd be just like sorting a list of objects based on an integer field

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more *efficient* to do the sorting in python rather than the database. Once you get a `list` of objects that have at least one tag, you can sort it using the `MyModel.tags.count()` attribute passed to the sorting comparison - it'd be just like sorting a list of objects based on an integer field

```python
# your query
objects = MyModel.objects.filter('...')

# sort in place
objects.sort(
    # set the sorting comparison to tag count
    key = lambda obj: obj.tags.count(),
    # if you want a descending comparison, highest tag count first
    # reverse = True
)
```

I say this would be more *efficient* because I assume that you're going to use all the objects anyways, rather than say, just get the first one (with highest tag count). So instead of making the database do the comparisons, you can do it in python itself.

Comment: objects is a queryset so it wouldn't have a sort function.  Also, I need my result to be queryset since I'm overriding get_queryset in a subclass of ListView.  Finally, how would obj.tags.count() give me the number of matching tags?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a (complicated) solution:

```
from django.db.models import Case, ExpressionWrapper, IntegerField, Q, Value, When

tag_list = ["tag1", "tag2"]

qs = MyModel.objects.filter(
    reduce(
        lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(tags__icontains=tag) for tag in tag_list]))

check_matches = map(
    lambda x: Case(
        When(Q(tags__icontains=x), then=Value(1)),
            default=Value(0)),
    tag_list)
count_matches = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, check_matches)
qs = qs.annotate(
    matches=ExpressionWrapper(
        count_matches,
        output_field=IntegerField()))
qs = qs.order_by('-matches')
```

Comment: I have attempted to duplicate this solution to only find that I cannot recreate it. I am being sent back the entirety of my table. Do you have any examples of this query available or able to give more context? I have posted a similar question here using your example [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068139/cant-get-queryset-to-return-list-of-objects-that-is-descending-by-tag-matches)