# Cant get queryset to return list of objects that is descending by tag matches

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I am running django 2.1.7, DRF and using taggit. I am writing my own custom queryset to find tags that an object has. 
The url:
**example.com/api/tags=books,headphones,sleep**

Should return JSON that has objects in order from contains most tags to contains at least one tag.
Here is the [gitgist](https://gist.github.com/lowkeyshift/9c3e2a0c9b012f9d8dd1a56bf85214b5)

```
from django.db.models import Case, ExpressionWrapper, IntegerField, Q, Value, When

class SpecialSearch(ListAPIView):
    model = Object
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, rs, value):
        """
        Recipe search matching, best matching and kind of matching,
        by filtering against `tags` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        if value:
            tags = [tag.strip() for tag in value.split(',')]
            qs = Object.objects.filter(
                reduce(
                    lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(tags__icontains=tag) for tag in tags]))
            check_matches = map(
                lambda x: Case(
                    When(Q(tags__icontains=x), then=Value(1)),
                        default=Value(0)),
            tags)
            count_matches = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, check_matches)
            qs = qs.annotate(
            matches=ExpressionWrapper(
                count_matches,
                output_field=IntegerField()))
            qs = qs.order_by('-matches')
        return qs
```

Currently, this code I submitted kind of works but is returning json that is ordered by the object ID and the API endpoint when submitting a new series of tags won't receive a new json dump from the API. I am totally lost right now. Any help would be absolutely appreciated.

Comment: Hi, your code is working "out of the box" in my case. Still, you should use `tags__iexact=tag` to avoid mismatch with a tag beeing a substring of another tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late for the OP, but in case anyone comes by looking at this, adding Sum() around count_matches might do the trick:

```
from django.db.models import (Case, ExpressionWrapper, IntegerField, Q, Value, When, Sum)

class SpecialSearch(ListAPIView):
    model = Object
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, rs, value):
        """
        Recipe search matching, best matching and kind of matching,
        by filtering against `tags` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        if value:
            tags = [tag.strip() for tag in value.split(',')]
            qs = Object.objects.filter(
                reduce(
                    lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(tags__icontains=tag) for tag in tags]))
            check_matches = map(
                lambda x: Case(
                    When(Q(tags__icontains=x), then=Value(1)),
                        default=Value(0)),
            tags)
            count_matches = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, check_matches)
            qs = qs.annotate(
            matches=ExpressionWrapper(
                Sum(count_matches),
                output_field=IntegerField()))
            qs = qs.order_by('-matches')
        return qs
```